# Select from dropdown using Selenium Python, front end app - react.js

Tags: python, selenium, reactjs

I want to select an item from a drop down using selenium python. The project uses `react.js`. The `dropdown` html appears in a div.

[code inspect for dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaHrT.png)

As this is under div, not select, when i try to select specific value, i got an error message.

Error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select
>   only works on  elements, not on div

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: use xpath or css selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use [`Select` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) to operate dropdowns which are not implemented using `select` and `option` elements.

You have to handle this kind of dropdown "manually" - generally speaking - click it to open it up, locate the desired dropdown item/option and click it. E.g., judging by you concise HTML snippet, to open up the dropdown you can try:

```
# open up the dropdown
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".Select-control")
# or dropdown = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".Select-control .Select-input")
dropdown.click()

# TODO: select option
```

Sometimes, simply focusing the dropdown and typing the desired item/option text would auto-select it - if this is the case, you can try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(dropdown).send_keys("Desired option text").perform()
```

And, if there are any animations or time delays (to, for example, retrieve the options from the server) you may need to add [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to handle the possible timing issues.

---

These are all general tips, I am operating under assumptions and I have no way to check if anything above works for your use case.